# "relation does not seem to exist" error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I wrote a Ruby on Rails app and it works fine locally. But when I deploy the the app to Heroku I get the following errors:

[image: here is photo of the error]

Here it is my page in local hosting:

[image: it is my page in localhosting]

Maybe this other screen of error could help a little bit more:

[image]

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't post code or errors in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: AAAaaaaa thanks in my next questions i gonna do that, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your database migrations haven't been run. This needs to be done on each of your databases separately. I.e., running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` on your local copy won't update the schema of your database on Heroku.

You can migrate your remote schema using the `heroku` CLI client:

```
heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If you've got multiple apps configured for this project make sure to include the `-a` / `--app` argument to choose where the command gets run.

If you want to migrate your database schema automatically as part of your deploy you can add a [release command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) to your `Procfile`, e.g.

```
release: bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This doesn't replace any other content your `Procfile` may contain. It should be added to whatever you already have.